# Referring to someone formally

Tags: personal-pronoun, formality

I'm talking about my Professor to his secretary. should I use "Sie" or "Er" or maybe "Der" when I refer to him?

Comment: Does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_pronouns#Personal_pronouns) answer your question? Note the distinction between second and third person pronouns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should most likely just go with *er* (assuming from your question that the professor is male), as pointed out by @infinitezero.

However, in cases where you want to be especially formal, you can also say "der Herr Professor" (with the approproate inflections, e.g. "dem Herrn Professor" etc.).

This construction also works with doctors, and is most commonly used when referring to medical doctors, e.g. "Ich habe einen Termin beim Herrn Doktor".

It should be noted though that this is *very* formal and can almost sound like sarcasm ("der feine Herr Professor" could be something you say to make fun of him for being aloof, for example).

Comment: No, never "der Herr Professor". Refer to them by title and name, e.g., "Ich habe einen Termin bei Professor Schmidt. Er/sie erwartet mich." Depending on your own standing, you might even skip the title and switch to "... bei Herrn Schmidt."

Comment: @Roland Of course, just using the entire title and name works (though that is against the premise of the question). Dropping the title, however, can be a major faux-pas. (Don't get me wrong: I hold no great love for any part of this title system, but some people absolutely do). As I wrote, "der Herr Professor" is formal to the point of being comical, but it absolutely is an existing construction.

Comment: I recommend not using this construction in an academic environment in Germany. As I said, if you can skip the title depends on your own standing (and on how formal the situation is).

Comment: It's true that in an academic environment, extreme formality is rare (after all, pretty much anyone is on a first-name-basis), but even in academia some environments are extremely hierarchical. In the end, it depends on context of course.

Comment: Maybe that's a regional difference, but the Austrian me would consider _beim Herrn Doktor/Professor/Ingenieur/Vizeleutnant_ a pretty standard, unmarked, polite form. Not overly formal and almost sarcastic. Title + Name is only necessary if the person is not clear from the context.

Answer (score 3):

The pronoun *Sie* (capital *S*) is only used when addressing a person, never when you refer to one.

You should use the pronouns *er/sie* when referring to people. *Der/die* is considered impolite, although people might use it unintentionally that way (so don't think about it too much, when you hear other people use it, but I would not recommend using it).

Answer (score 0):

For pronouns the formal/familiar distinction only matters in the second person. You'd only use "sie" for a female professor, and "er" for a male professor. You'd rarely use "der" when talking to the person directly, and you'd mainly use it as a relative pronoun. (The same goes for "die".) For example "Das war der Professor, der letztes Jahr Philosophie unterrichtet hat." You can also use "der" as a demonstrative pronoun, and for an English speaker the difference be this and "er" can be subtle. But my understanding is that it can be used if you're talking about someone mentioned previously but only in passing. Of course there are all sorts of ways to refer to someone informally, even insultingly, in the third person if you're not using a pronoun, for example "der Typ" or "der Kerl".